# Bootstrap - Show an error message on button click

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a jquery newbie. I'm using bootstrap on my webpage and i want to show an error message on user click.

```
        $("Btn_register").on('click', function () {
        $(".alert").alert();
    });
```

Code is working but it shows error message also when page loads. I need to hide the message and show only on click event. I tried adding;

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $(".alert").hide();
    });
```

But that didn't worked. Can you help me hiding the error message on page load?

HTML code for error is:

```
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
<strong>Error!</strong> A problem has been occurred while submitting your data.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the alert to `display: none` with CSS. It will be easier to give your alert an ID, such as `id="myAlert"` and in your CSS you would have `#myAlert { display: none; }`. Then when it's time to show the alert, you can just use jQuery to show it: `$('#myAlert').fadeIn()`.

Here's a jsFiddle to show you how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/kqCZ8/

In your code you also had `$("Btn_register").on('click', function () {`. If "Btn_register" is an ID, you need to reference it with the pound symbol at the beginning, e.g. `$("#Btn_register")`

Comment: I made a jsFiddle for you, since there were some more errors in your code. I'll update my answer with the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Bootstrap "Alertify": http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/
The link provides all what you have to do. Just download the files, include the script and styles in your  and start using them. Its an easy, nice and elegant way to show small alerts.